# Remove repeating portion from a text file without deleting the first occurance

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a text file that looks like this.

> Name: Python
>
> Address: apple
>
> This is a sample text.
>
> It could start with different text text2.
>
> End
>
> This is where file starts....
>
> What is going on
>
> Yeah
>
> abble
>
> Name: Python
>
> Address: apple
>
> This is a different text.
>
> End
>
> There is another stuff that is written.
>
> What should I do.
>
> This
>
> What is going on

I am trying to remove everything between Name: and End except keep everything before Name: and End

```
import re
with open('testfile.txt') as csvfiles: 
    data=csvfiles.read()

print (re.sub('Name.*?End','',data, flags=re.DOTALL))
```

The result I am looking for is:

> Name: Python
>
> Address: apple
>
> This is a sample text.
>
> It could start with different text text2.
>
> End
>   This is where file starts....
>
> What is going on
>
> Yeah
>
> abble
>
> There is another stuff that is written.
>
> What should I do.
>
> This
>
> What is going on

What I am getting is :

> This is where file starts....
>
> What is going on
>
> Yeah
>
> abble
>
> There is another stuff that is written.
>
> What should I do.
>
> This
>
> What is going on

How do I keep 1st occurrence from Name to End and delete every thing between Name: and End

Thank you, 
Shone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be the fastest solution, but you can use a regular expression to find all occurences of your pattern and replace all but the first with `''`.

Here is a regular expression that will match your pattern: [`(?m)^(Name[\s\S]*?End|\Z)`](https://regex101.com/r/3wiJIS/1)

```
import re

with open('test.txt') as f:
  data = f.read()
  x = re.findall(r'(?m)^(Name[\s\S]*?End|\Z)', data)
  for i in x[1:]:
    data = data.replace(i, '')

  print(data)
```

Output:

```
Name: Python

Address: apple

This is a sample text.

It could start with different text text2.

End

This is where file starts....

What is going on

Yeah

abble



There is another stuff that is written.

What should I do.

This

What is going on
```

Comment: I see what you did. It might be slow if file gets bigger but It works for me so I will take it. Thank you

Comment: A faster alternative would be to `split` the file after the first match, then use your current `re.sub()` method after.